# Golang autoreload on Goland (Jetbrains IDE)?

Tags: go, goland

I'm currently using [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) to autoreload my app, but I wanted to know if it was possible to autoreload directly from Goland IDE?

this is the command I always use to autoreload:

```
gin --all --immediate --path . --build .
```

I have googled for documentation but can't find any info about livereload from Goland IDE.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and somebody pointed me to this thread https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11119#focus=Comments-27-4901631.0-0 which explains a work around to hot reload upon code changes using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions plugin.

- Install [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin
- Navigate to Preferences / Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Quick Lists and create a new one with the Run/Debug option.
- Navigate to Preferences / Settings | Save Actions and enable Activate actions on save & Execute an action, select Run Configuration).

Comment: Thanks - it works, but how to select not default configuration?

Comment: I recorded the macros for the click to rerun button on the active Debug tab. It's works good, just keep the active needed debug tab.

Answer (score 0):

The "Go Build" run configuration does not have an auto-reload feature (as opposed to the "Go Test" one which does).

You can use the builtin Terminal (ALT+F12), to run the command you mentioned and even use a different tab for that.

If you need this feature, please open an issue on [the tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go).